# PhantomJS includeJS not working

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, phantomjs

I'm trying to use `PhantomJS` in order to get data from a website like this:

```
app.get('/scrape', function(req, res) {
var _ph, _page;
phantom.create()
.then(function (ph) {
    _ph = ph;
    return ph.createPage();
})
.then(function (page) {
    _page = page; 
    var url = "https://banc.nl/";
    return page.open(url);
})
.then(function(page) {
    page.includeJs('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js', function() {
    page.evaluate(function() {
        $('.sc-dnqmqq kaMmif').filter(function () {
            var data = $(this);
            price = data.children().first().text();
            console.log("Price: " + price);
        });
    });
    });
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.log("Error: " , err);
    _page.close();
    //_ph.exit();
});
});
```

The problem is that I get the following error: `Error:  TypeError: page.includeJs is not a function`

If I uncomment the `ph.exit()` I will get a warning also: `warn: exit() was called before waiting for commands to finish. Make sure you are not calling exit() prematurely.`

I found several questions about this in SO but non of the answers solved my problem.

Comment: What is your node.js version? Can you migrate to 8.x if it's lower?

Comment: My node.js version is `v8.11.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of [phantomjs-node](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node) module uses Promises so we can rewrite scripts using `async` functions with `await` operator — much more readable:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
var url = 'https://www.huobipro.com';

(async function(req, res) {
    const instance = await phantom.create();
    const page = await instance.createPage();

    await page.on('onConsoleMessage', function(msg) {
        console.info(msg);
    });
    await page.on('onError', function(msg) {
        console.info(msg);
    });

    const status = await page.open(url);
    await console.log('STATUS:', status);

    // Wait a bit for javascript to load and run
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000))

    await page.includeJs('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js');
    await page.evaluate(function() {
        $('span[price]').filter(function () {
            var data = $(this);
            console.log("Price: " + data.text());
        });
    });

    await instance.exit();
})();
```

Comment: Had to use another coin market site — banc.nl didn't have any listings on the home page.